# How can I connect a call between 2 app users using Twilio and record it?

Tags: twilio

I have a use case where my app users want to contact my business agents. User and agents both have mobile phones to connect. So when any user makes a call it should get forwarded to dedicated agents of the users through Twilio. So I don't know how to achieve this? And along with this how to record this call.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Assuming you have a number(s), you have to do it catch the incoming call, go to [manage-numbers](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers), within voice in the `A CALL COMES IN` section, give a twiml.
2. Check if you don't already have [twimls](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins) create a new one and within it you can mention:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Response> <Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual">` `<Number>AgentNumber</Number> </Dial> </Response>`

In place of `AgentNumber`, give the number of the agent corresponding to the user.
This is assuming you have dedicated numbers for each user, which generally isn't the case. If you have the same number but want to handle incoming calls separately, you can work with something more dynamic like webhook in place of twiml.

3. If you decide to work with webhook, in every incoming call twilio will give you a parameter map containing all the details like which number its being placed from etc, check [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls)

One thing more, you can also do configurations at an app level rather than at number level in which case you need to find how the TwimlApp is configured, but you will still find that in manager numbers section.